# Is an explicitly deleted destructor implicitly marked constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++20

When explicitly *defaulting* a destructor (e.g.: `struct s { ~s() = default; };`), it seems that the type can still be used in a `constexpr` context. However, when explicitly *deleting* a destructor (e.g.: `struct s { ~s() = delete; };`), Clang no longer thinks the type is viable for a `constexpr` context. So, as the title suggests, can a type with an explicitly deleted destructor still be used in a `constexpr` context?

```
struct a { ~a() = default; };           // all ok
struct b { ~b(){} };                    // all fail
struct c { ~c() = delete; };            // fails on clang
struct d { constexpr ~d() = default; }; // all ok
struct e { constexpr ~e(){} };          // all ok
struct f { constexpr ~f() = delete; };  // all ok

static_assert(noexcept([]<c>{}));
```

The error produced by Clang 16.0.0 and Clang trunk:

```
<source>:9:28: error: non-type template parameter has non-literal type 'c'
static_assert(noexcept([]<c>{}));
                           ^
<source>:3:12: note: 'c' is not literal because its destructor is not constexpr
struct c { ~c() = delete; };            // fails on clang
           ^
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/cTjhKohGx)

Comment: `[dcl.fct.def.default]` has a lot about `constexpr` but `[dcl.fct.def.delete]` doesn't mention it  even once.

Answer (score 15):

For a class to be a literal type, all you need is a `constexpr` destructor. `= delete`d functions have been allowed to be `constexpr` [for a long time](https://wg21.link/CWG1199).

However, if you don't mark it `constexpr`, then it isn't `constexpr` except defaulted destructors which have an extra rule ([[class.dtor]p9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.dtor#9)):

> A defaulted destructor is a constexpr destructor if it satisfies the requirements for a constexpr destructor ([dcl.constexpr]).

Which a class with no members does, so `~a() = default;` is constexpr.
`~c() = delete;` isn't constexpr because there's no reason for it to be.
`constexpr ~f() = delete;` is constexpr because it's marked `constexpr`.

Clang is correct here: `~s() = delete;` would not be `constexpr` if it is not specified to be, so can't be used as a literal type. It seems that `std::is_literal_v<c>` passes in gcc erroneously.

Comment: Isn't it weird to talk about `constexpr`-ness of a function that is `delete`d?..

Comment: @evg I'll say.  Even marking a destructor as deleted does my head in.

Comment: @Evg Here's another case where deleted functions constexpr-ness makes a difference: <https://godbolt.org/z/hdxKW8ds4>. I just view this as the standard being too strict on requirements (Why do literal types need a constexpr destructor when you can use them without destroying them? Why do literal types need a constexpr non-copy constructor?) But since this will never affect any real code, there's really no reason to change it.

Comment: If there is an extra rule for *defaulted* destructors concerning `constexpr`ness, one could argue—even just in terms of symmetry—that the same should apply to *deleted* destructors as well. Maybe it would help if the standard was more clear about this, as your answer implies that the behavior of the GCC and MSVC compiler is not compliant to the C++20 standard. For now, I think the right thing to do is to submit a bug report to GCC and see what comes out of that.

Comment: Also, you've put the question that I repeated in the body of the post out of context. *"can a type with an explicitly deleted destructor still be used in a `constexpr` context?"* obviously refers to an explicitly deleted destructor that is implicitly marked `constexpr` (not explicitly marked `constexpr`), as the title suggests. So, the example you show has no relevance to the question asked, and I think you should edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @303 Defaulted default constructors/copy constructors can be implicitly `constexpr` as well, so this is in line with how `= default` works everywhere else. Deleted constructors are also not implicitly constexpr, but this is a little more difficult to observe: <https://godbolt.org/z/x9jETshq9>. So behaviour for destructors is consistent with for constructors.

Answer (score 3):

Per cppreference:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

> **constexpr variable**
>
> A **constexpr variable** must satisfy the following requirements:
>
> - ...
> - (since C++20) it must have constant destruction, i.e. either:
>
>   - it is not of class type nor (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof, or
>   - it is of class type or (possibly multi-dimensional) array thereof, **that class type has a constexpr destructor**, and for a hypothetical expression `e` whose only effect is to destroy the object, `e` would be a core constant expression if the lifetime of the object and its non-mutable subobjects (but not its mutable subobjects) were considered to start within `e`.
>
> ...
>
> **constexpr destructor**
>
> (until C++20) Destructors cannot be constexpr, but a [trivial destructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Trivial_destructor) can be implicitly called in constant expressions.
>
> (since C++20) A constexpr destructor whose function body is not `=delete;` must satisfy the following additional requirement:
>
> - every destructor used to destroy non-static data members and base class must be a constexpr destructor.